# Parse XML File Based on Extensions

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing

I am working on a project which has below requirement. Example:

FileExtensions = .txt , .xml, .xmls (here .txt file can also contain xml types)
FolderPath = C:\Parse\

If Extension is .txt

Search All folders and subfolders for .txt

Read .txt file and search for

```
<data name="original" xml:space="preserve">
<value>//something/folder/hello.txt</value>
```

if found: hello.txt should be passed to another function()

LOOP SAME AGAIN

EXIT

Similarly for other extensions

If Extension is .xml

Read .xml file and search for

```
<data name="NewType" xml:space="preserve">
<value>//something/folder/kino/hello.xml</value>
```

if found: hello.xml should be passed to another function()

LOOP SAME AGAIN

EXIT

same for other file types ....

Kindly assist me how to proceed. Searching files I am aware but parsing each file by getting the value of filename within and run the function what confusing me!

-Kino

Comment: you want to read .txt file or you are parsing a directory?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What works, what doesn't? Please add the code you have an actual problem with.

Comment: I am able to retrieve files recursively in folders and subfolders. But not sure how to go about reading files and taking filename and passing to another function.